# Are 操る, 釣る, 連れる, 移る and 吊る(つる) etymologically related?

Tags: etymology

These words, in addition to sharing a common sound (つる) are somewhat related in sense, perhaps through a derivation like to hang > to lure (for fishes) > to follow > to move >to manipulate, or something like that

The problem is that I cannot identify the あや element of 操る (perhaps it is related to 文 ?) and the う portion of 移る

Are these words actually related ?